# Measure the performance of a Redis Lua script

Tags: lua, redis

Is there any way to measure the performance of a Redis Lua script?

I have a lua script and I ended up to a slightly different implementation and I am wondering if there is any way to measure which of the two implementations is faster.

Comment: Does Redis provide os.clock in Lua?

Comment: @lhf no, the `os` lib isn't available in Redis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call Redis' `TIME` command to perform in-script "benchmarking". Something like the following should work:

```
local start = redis.call('TIME')

-- your logic here

local finish = redis.call('TIME')
return finish[1]-start[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just one comment, in my case it would be better to subtract the microseconds elements from finish/start (return finish[2] - start[2]), otherwise the result is always 0 since the execution time in Redis is extremely fast ;)

Comment: Yeah, I "deliberately" avoided the ms complexities and left it as an exercise for the reader - happy Lua days 8-)

Comment: ^^^ avoided in order to make the snippet simple (and becauze I'm laaazy)

Answer (score 2):

I read in the comments that someone mensioned finish[2]-start[2] which is not a good idea because [2] has "the amount of microseconds already elapsed in the current second" and not the entire timestamp (so if we finish in a different second, this calculation will fail.)

based on: https://redis.io/commands/TIME

to get time as microseconds, I would do:

```
local start = redis.call('TIME')

-- your logic here

local finish = redis.call('TIME')
return (finish[1]-start[1])*1000000+(finish[2]-start[2])
```